# Does embedded jetty support java 8 compact profiles?

Tags: java, java-8, embedded-jetty

We are trying to build java based applications that work with java 8 compact profiles. We have to include a lightweight web interface with these applications. Does embedded jetty support compact profiles? If not, are there any other embedded servlet containers that can support compact profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to build your own, but note that the Jetty build actually has that available already.

This artifact is intentionally not published anywhere, as java8 compact3 is *VERY* unreliable/unstable in our experience.  Every JVM release has its own tweaks that can render different behavior.  We just don't have the bandwidth to support compact3 beyond the build artifact.

See: [jetty.project/aggregates/jetty-all-compact3](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/tree/jetty-9.3.x/aggregates/jetty-all-compact3)

You can build it this way.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project.git
$ cd jetty.project
$ mvn clean install -Dtest=None -Pcompact3
$ ls aggregates/jetty-all-compact3/target
```

> Note: anything needing a compiler (JSP, JXF, etc), or bytecode scanning (for annotations mainly), does not work in compact3.

Comment: Is it better to wait for Java 9 modular approach than trying to implement using the compact profiles?